# Can't install or run Wine

Tags: wine

I am a pretty novice user and have just recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my six year-old laptop as a dual boot with Windows. I installed with the simple Windows Installer and haven't done any major adjustments to Ubuntu other than to install the beta of Google Music Uploader for Ubuntu.

I just recently tried to use get Wine so I can run EAC (Exact Audio Copy). However, whenever I run the command in the terminal to get Wine 1.5, I errors.

For example, if I out in this command: "sudo apt-get install wine"

I get this:

```
"Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."
```

When I input this "sudo apt-get install wine1.5" I get this:

```
"Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.5 : Depends: wine1.5-i386 (= 1.5.25-0ubuntu1) but it is not installable
           Recommends: gnome-exe-thumbnailer but it is not going to be installed or
                       kde-runtime but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: fonts-droid but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: ttf-mscorefonts-installer but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: fonts-horai-umefont but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: fonts-unfonts-core but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: winbind but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: winetricks but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."
```

Before this I tried the same with Wine1.4. Same error messages.

Any ideas? I'm pretty new to Ubuntu and the open-source world, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try following the instructions [here](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu).   They are pretty easy to follow.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just tried this. Still getting the "package dependencies cannot be resolved" with those instructions.

Comment: @user136862 I have had a similar problem before. Have you tried installing it via synaptic?

Comment: Nope. Totally ignorant as to Synaptic. I'm pretty new to Ubuntu. How would I go about trying that?

Comment: @user136862 press `alt+F2`, type in `synaptic`, press enter. Then after synaptic starts type `wine` into the search bar. Then click on the check-mark box next to what want to install. A menu should come up, then click on `mark for installation`. Then click on the the big `Apply` button somewhere on the top.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sudo apt-get install wine` If this does not fix the problem then follow the instructions in this [Package Manager Troubleshooting Procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure) and we will try to help you on the [Launchpad Ubuntu Answers Forum](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+questions)

Comment: Just went through the Package Manager Troubleshooting Procedure guide. Posted the question at the Forum under Question #223259

Answer (score 0):

First check your repositories and give us if possible. If everything was ok then `sudo apt-get update` may fix this. Else try to install it from `ppa`:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Comment: Dumb question: how do I check the repositories? As said, I am a novice to this.

Comment: Go to `system settings` > `Software sources` > `Other software`. Some ppa can cause trouble. make sure that every thing is standard.

Comment: There are 4 things:

Added by software-center; credentials stored in /etc/apt/auth.conf
http://dl.google.com/linux/musicmanager/deb/
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu

Obviously one of those is the Google Music Manager.

Comment: Try to remove them (wine ppa) first, then `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install wine` if it was done then bingo! else re add them using commands above, and try to install again. Hope it works ...

Comment: No dice. Cleared out the wine ppa, ran the commands, no dice. Tried the above commands before that. No dice. Any other approach I should take?

Comment: This is not a standard solution, but helped me a lot. Install `synaptic`, and using synaptic try to install `wine`, then it will give you error that some packages are not going to install, so you try to install them, and follow this step while you can find the `exact package` that is not going to install, then we can think about it more. (synaptic make it easier to follow dependency tree)

Comment: I'll have to try synaptic tomorrow. It's midnight where I am and I must sleep. Thanks! I'll try it later and will report back